# SQLITE3 on STM32 FreeRTOS and FATFS

Tags: sqlite, stm32, freertos, fatfs

I am trying to port SQLITE3 on top of FatFs supported by the STM32Cube using the FreeRTOS and MicroSD Card on STM32F429-EVAL1 board.
Could you please share the source if anyone is successful with this implementation?

I see that I can use test_demovfs.c file from sqlite3, but need to figure out how to integrate it with the FatFs-based project. Any support in this regard is highly appreciable.

Comment: Never mind, please. I made it work finally.

Comment: Please help me I am doing the same but for STM32H7 + freeRTOS + FATFS. What was the problem and how did you solve it? Would be nice if you answer and accept your own answer here.